# How to replace the first n elements in each row of a dataframe that are larger than a certain threshold

Tags: python, performance, pandas, dataframe

I have a huge dataframe that contains only numbers (the one I show below is just for demonstration purposes). My goal is to replace in each row of the dataframe the first `n` numbers that are larger than a certain value `val` by 0.

To give an example:

My dataframe could look like this:

```
   c1  c2  c3  c4
0  38  10   1   8
1  44  12  17  46
2  13   6   2   7
3   9  16  13  26
```

If I now choose `n = 2` (number of replacements) and `val = 10`, my desired output would look like this:

```
   c1  c2  c3  c4
0   0  10   1   8
1   0   0  17  46
2   0   6   2   7
3   9   0   0  26
```

In the first row, only one value is larger than `val` so only one gets replaced, in the second row all values are larger than `val` but only the first two can be replaced. Analog for rows 3 and 4 (please note that not only the first two columns are affected but the first two values in a row which can be in any column).

A straightforward and very ugly implementation could look like this:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(1)

col1 = [np.random.randint(1, 50) for ti in xrange(4)]
col2 = [np.random.randint(1, 50) for ti in xrange(4)]
col3 = [np.random.randint(1, 50) for ti in xrange(4)]
col4 = [np.random.randint(1, 50) for ti in xrange(4)]

df = pd.DataFrame({'c1': col1, 'c2': col2, 'c3': col3, 'c4': col4})

val = 10
n = 2

for ind, row in df.iterrows():
    # number of replacements
    re = 0

    for indi, vali in enumerate(row):
        if vali > val:
            df.iloc[ind, indi] = 0
            re += 1
            if re == n:
                break
```

That works but I am sure that there are much more efficient ways of doing this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write your own a bit weird function and use [`apply`](https://www.google.ru/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjQ7LTY0sfKAhVJwHIKHbT0BFMQFggbMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fpandas.pydata.org%2Fpandas-docs%2Fversion%2F0.17.1%2Fgenerated%2Fpandas.DataFrame.apply.html&usg=AFQjCNEV-3rhym9xF5j7u78SpzSm6Ra4PA&bvm=bv.112766941,d.bGQ) with `axis=1`:

```
def f(x, n, m):
    y = x.copy()
    y[y[y > m].iloc[:n].index] = 0
    return y

In [380]: df
Out[380]:
   c1  c2  c3  c4
0  38  10   1   8
1  44  12  17  46
2  13   6   2   7
3   9  16  13  26

In [381]: df.apply(f, axis=1, n=2, m=10)
Out[381]:
   c1  c2  c3  c4
0   0  10   1   8
1   0   0  17  46
2   0   6   2   7
3   9   0   0  26
```

*Note*: `y = x.copy()` needs to make a copy of the series. If you need to change your values inplace you could omit that line. You need extra `y` because with slicing you'll get a copy not the original object.

Comment: That seems to give a wrong output. The 13 in the last row should be replaced as well.

Comment: Why? As I understand you need to compare only 2 first columns... Am I understand you wrong?

Comment: Oh, yes, you misunderstood: It is about the first two values in a row but they can be in any column. That is the part I am struggling with; how to select the first n columns?