# How to replace only the first n elements in a numpy array that are larger than a certain value?

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy

I have an array `myA` like this:

```
array([ 7,  4,  5,  8,  3, 10])
```

If I want to replace all values that are larger than a value `val` by 0, I can simply do:

```
myA[myA > val] = 0
```

which gives me the desired output (for `val = 5`):

```
 array([0, 4, 5, 0, 3, 0])
```

However, my goal is to replace not all but only the first `n` elements of this array that are larger than a value `val`.

So, if `n = 2` my desired outcome would look like this (`10` is the third element and should therefore not been replaced):

```
array([ 0,  4,  5,  0,  3, 10])
```

A straightforward implementation would be:

```
import numpy as np

myA = np.array([7, 4, 5, 8, 3, 10])
n = 2
val = 5

# track the number of replacements
repl = 0

for ind, vali in enumerate(myA):

    if vali > val:

        myA[ind] = 0
        repl += 1

        if repl == n:
            break
```

That works but maybe someone can can up with a smart way of masking!?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following should work:

```
myA[(myA > val).nonzero()[0][:2]] = 0
```

since [nonzero](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.nonzero.html) will return the indexes where the boolean array `myA > val` is non zero e.g. `True`.

For example:

```
In [1]: myA = array([ 7,  4,  5,  8,  3, 10])

In [2]: myA[(myA > 5).nonzero()[0][:2]] = 0

In [3]: myA
Out[3]: array([ 0,  4,  5,  0,  3, 10])
```

Comment: Very elegant, thanks. I upvote it for now and might accept it later on depending on the other answers' quality.

Answer (score 2):

Final solution is very simple:

```
import numpy as np
myA = np.array([7, 4, 5, 8, 3, 10])
n = 2
val = 5

myA[np.where(myA > val)[0][:n]] = 0

print(myA)
```

Output:

```
[ 0  4  5  0  3 10]
```

Comment: That seems to fail when n = 3.

Comment: Yep, that should be `np.where(mask)[0][n:]`

Comment: Yes, now it works fine as well, so I upvote it, too and might accept it later on depending on the other answers' quality.

Comment: Very nice. You can make it a one-liner like JuniorCompressor's answer: `myA[np.where(myA > val)[0][:n]] = 0`

Comment: @mtrw Yes, I can, but the `VisibleDeprecationWarning: boolean index did not match indexed array along dimension 0; dimension is 6 but corresponding boolean dimension is 2
  myA[mask[np.where(mask)[0][n:]]] = 0` warning is raised.

Comment: @GeorgePetrov - the one-liner should not need `mask`. If you use the `np.where` answer to index `myA` you don't get the warning.

Comment: @mtrw Thanks, I made some changes to the solution, now it's only one line.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another possibility (untested), probably no better than `nonzero`:

```
def truncate_mask(m, stop):
  m = m.astype(bool, copy=False) #  if we allow non-bool m, the next line becomes nonsense
  return m & (np.cumsum(m) <= stop)

myA[truncate_mask(myA > val, n)] = 0
```

By avoiding building and using an explicit index you might end up with slightly better performance...but you'd have to test it to find out.

**Edit 1:** while we're on the subject of possibilities, you could also try:

```
def truncate_mask(m, stop):
   m = m.astype(bool, copy=True) #  note we need to copy m here to safely modify it
   m[np.searchsorted(np.cumsum(m), stop):] = 0
   return m
```

**Edit 2 (the next day):** I've just tested this and it seems that `cumsum` is actually worse than `nonzero`, at least with the [kinds of values](https://gist.github.com/d1manson/6b358e8f92b89ee76325) I was using (so neither of the above approaches is worth using).  Out of curiosity, I also tried it with numba:

```
import numba

@numba.jit
def set_first_n_gt_thresh(a, val, thresh, n):
    ii = 0
    while n>0 and ii < len(a):
        if a[ii] > thresh:
            a[ii] = val
            n -= 1
        ii += 1
```

This only iterates over the array once, or rather it only iterates over the necessary part of the array once, never even touching the latter part.  This gives you vastly superior performance for small `n`, but even for the worst case of `n>=len(a)` this approach is faster.

Comment: There is one small 'mistake' in the code: it should be `<=stop` instead of `stop`, the it seems to work fine. Thanks for the suggestion, I upvote it as well.

Comment: Ahh, yes (I was thinking in terms of slice notation).  I've added a second variation on this, which might also contain errors.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the same solution as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35015414/how-to-replace-the-first-n-elements-in-each-row-of-a-dataframe-that-are-larger-t) with converting you `np.array` to `pd.Series`:

```
s = pd.Series([ 7,  4,  5,  8,  3, 10])
n = 2
m = 5
s[s[s>m].iloc[:n].index] = 0

In [416]: s
Out[416]:
0     0
1     4
2     5
3     0
4     3
5    10
dtype: int64
```

Step by step explanation:

```
In [426]: s > m
Out[426]:
0     True
1    False
2    False
3     True
4    False
5     True
dtype: bool

In [428]: s[s>m].iloc[:n]
Out[428]:
0    7
3    8
dtype: int64

In [429]: s[s>m].iloc[:n].index
Out[429]: Int64Index([0, 3], dtype='int64')

In [430]: s[s[s>m].iloc[:n].index]
Out[430]:
0    7
3    8
dtype: int64
```

Output in `In[430]` looks the same as `In[428]` but in 428 it's a copy and in 430 original series.

If you'll need `np.array` you could use `values` method:

```
In [418]: s.values
Out[418]: array([ 0,  4,  5,  0,  3, 10], dtype=int64)
```

Comment: Great, that works fine! Also thanks for the detailed explanation. I upvote it for now and might accept it later on depending on the quality of other answers.